# getting data from the input file to output to a file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

this is my code wondering why it will not read from the file. or a better question would be how to have the student name be drawn from the file. What am I doing wrong?

```
int semestersCompleted;
int gpa;
double semesterDiscount;
double semesterDiscount;
double gpaDiscount;
double totalDiscount;
string studentName;

int main(void)
{

    outFile << "Task 1 - tuition Discount" << endl;

    ifstream dataFile;
    ofstream outFile;

    getline(dataFile, studentName, '\n');

    dataFile >> semestersCompleted;
    dataFile >> gpa;


    dataFile.ignore(100, '\n');

    outFile << "Name: " << studentName << endl; 
    outFile << "Semester Completed: " << semestersCompleted << endl;
    outFile << "GPA: " << gpa << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can we please see the input file and the declarations/initializations of `dataFile` and `outFile`?

Comment: Thanks for posting the whole program. It seems that you are *declaring* an ifstream and an ofstream, but you are not actually intiailizing them to read or write from/to any file. Try adding `dataFile.open("input_file");` and then `outFile.open("output_file");`.

Comment: Did you ever open your input file with `dataFile.open("foobar.txt")`?

Comment: So for everyone asking, I do have the files open and it prints "Task 1 - tuition Discount" to the output file just not reading the input file to write out for studentName (I'm so sorry still a newbie )

Comment: Check if the file is open with `dataFile.is_open()` . If it returns false, then you know that the program cannot correctly open the file. Most IDEs read the input file directly if it is in the debug folder, otherwise use the file path. Edit: Your code does not show that your dataFile did not open any file.

Comment: @Daniel if (dataFile.is_open("Lab5In-1.txt"));

Comment: @Zamaire is_open() does not take any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you open the input file with

```
 ifstream dataFile;
 dataFile.open("Lab5ln-1.txt");
```

Then you can read input from it with

```
 dataFile >> semestersCompleted >> gpa;
```

Of course, you're going to want to make sure the file opened correctly with something like `cout << dataFile.is_open();` that simply returns a boolean value if the file opened properly. You can open it with just the filename if it is in the debug folder of your IDE (or in the same directory), otherwise you can use the full path to open it - i.e. `dataFile.open("c:/foo/bar.txt")`